# How to define events for dynamically created element in pure JS?

Tags: javascript

How to catch elements `onclick` event when element may be created in future or added dynamically?

```
// Here i need to define function for click
// In jQuery it would be like this: jQuery('body').on('click', 'a.some-link-class', function(){});

var some_link = document.createElement('a');
    some_link.class = 'some-link-class';
    some_link.href = '#';

var some_link_text = document.createTextNode('Some Link Title');
    some_link.appendChild(some_link_text);

document.body.appendChild(some_link);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You must use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) for JS. just attach an event to a parent item or document and check in the parent if trigger is your element. You can use a class name or tag name etc.

```
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ",e.target.id.replace("post-")," was clicked!");
    }
});
```

in this way the event also works for elements what will be added afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an event to the body and test if the source of the event is the control type you want, or a class, or something else.

```
//attach the event to everything in the body
document.body.addEventListener('click', eventFunction, false);

//event function
function eventFunction(e)
{
   //test if the source triggering the event is an element from the class you want
   //you can do the test on the class, tagname... anything you desire
   if(e.ClassName.match('myclass'))
   {
      //do something if the class matches
      dosomething();
   }
}
```

With this, you can create any element you want after that. If they have the good class they will trigger the event if clicked and the function will run.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach it when you create it:

```
some_link.onclick = function() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: But what if it's for multiple elements, some of which exist, and some that don't?

Comment: @Scimonster He could just attach the event handlers later the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
some_link.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

or

```
some_link.onclick = handler;
```